# auto update in electron app is not working

Tags: javascript, electron, auto-update, electron-forge, github-release

i am using electron forge, auto-updater for auto updating electron app but after running electron forge publish its working fine but not getting any updates. Below are the package.json, main.js and forge.config.js files which i am using

main.js

```js
const { BrowserWindow, app, ipcMain, autoUpdater ,Notification, dialog, Menu } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let win = null;

let version = app.getVersion()
console.log(version)
autoUpdater.autoDownload = false;
autoUpdater.autoInstallOnAppQuit = true;

const isDev = !app.isPackaged;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      sandbox: false
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html');
  if (isDev) win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

if (isDev) {
  const ignoredPattern = /Input|Output|node_modules|[\/\\]\./;
  require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron'),
    ignored: ignoredPattern
  })
}

const template = [
  {
    id: "home",
    label: "Home",
    submenu: [
      {
        label: `Current Version v${app.getVersion()}`,
        click: async() => {
          new Notification({title: 'Current Version', body: app.getVersion()}).show()
          await autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
        }
      },
      {
      label: "Exit",
      click() {
        app.quit();
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

//if mac add empty object to menuTemplate
if (process.platform == "darwin") {
  template.unshift({ label: "" }); //adding it to the beggining of the array
}

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

ipcMain.on('notify', (_, message) => {
  new Notification({ title: 'Notifiation', body: message }).show();
})

ipcMain.handle('get-app-path', () => {
  return app.getAppPath();
});


app.whenReady().then( () => { createWindow() })

// ********

const server = `https://github.com/Bhavik2205/Dicom_Viewer.git` //'https://github.com/ANIRBARASKAR/xray_dicon_hospital_project'
const url = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`

autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url })

setInterval(() => {
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
}, 1000)

autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
  new Notification({ title: 'Notifiation', body: info }).show();
  dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    message: `Current version ${app.getVersion()} .A new update is available. Do you want to download and install it now?`,
    buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
  }).then((result) => {
    if(result.response === 0) {
      let la = template2[0];
      la.submenu[0].label = 'Downloading latest version';
      autoUpdater.downloadUpdate();
    }
  });
    // autoUpdater.downloadUpdate();
});


autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
  new Notification({ title: 'Notifiation', body: info }).show();
  dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    message: 'You are already using the latest version of the app.',
  });
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  new Notification({ title: 'Notifiation', body: releaseName }).show();
  const dialogOpts = {
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Restart', 'Later'],
    title: 'Application Update',
    message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
    detail:
      'A new version has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.'
  }

  dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts).then((returnValue) => {
    if (returnValue.response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()
  })
})

autoUpdater.on('error', (message) => {
  new Notification({error: message})
  console.error('There was a problem updating the application')
  console.error("Hello", message)
})
```

forge.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    icon: './img/logo.icns',
    ignore: ["^/src($|/)"],
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
      platforms: ["darwin"],
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  publishers: [
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/publisher-github",
      config: {
        repository: {
          owner: "Bhavik2205",
          name: "Dicom_Viewer",
        },
        prerelease: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "electron-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "the sample description",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.src.js --watch",
    "dev": "electron .",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "anir": "concurrently \"npm run watch\" \"npm start\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Bhavik Patel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/publisher-github": "^6.4.2",
    "ajv": "^8.12.0",
    "ajv-formats": "^2.1.1",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "cornerstone-core": "^2.6.1",
    "cornerstone-file-image-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^5.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "smalltalk": "^4.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.7",
    "ulid": "^2.3.0",
    "update-electron-app": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "electron": "^22.2.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-cornerstone-viewport": "^4.1.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.11",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.82.1",
    "webpack-cli": "5.0.1"
  }
}
```

i want to implement autoupdate by which i can regularly send the updates to my all the clients by releasing the latest version on github.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).